# Why is only one of my two modals showing?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals on the same page. One of them shows just fine. The second one, however, doesn't show. Only the dark "opacity" screen shows, but not the modal itself. I've read other posts and nothing seems to work for me.

[Here's my codepen](https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/mvGJqV?editors=1000)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPublishWithAccount">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<!-- MODAL THAT WORKS -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modalPublishWithAccount">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
      I'm the modal that works
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /MODAL THAT WORKS -->

  <!-- MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal" style="z-index:10;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
         I'm the modal that doesn't work
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the inline z:index to 10000 or something larger than 10 you will be able to interact with the modal.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPublishWithAccount">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<!-- MODAL THAT WORKS -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modalPublishWithAccount">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
      I'm the modal that works
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /MODAL THAT WORKS -->

  <!-- MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->
  <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal" style="z-index:10000;">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
         I'm the modal that doesn't work
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This works with the code I shared. However, my site has many modals, about 5, and when I change the z-index as you mention, it still won't show.

Comment: Here's the code that doesn't work: https://codepen.io/paulamourad/pen/mvGJqV?editors=1000

Answer (score 1):

After many attempts, I hadn't closed one `</div>` tag. That was it!

Answer (score 0):

You have an inline style using a z-index. Just remove the z-index completely; Bootstrap handles the levels for you.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPublishWithAccount">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success mt-4 ml-2 mb-4" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal">Usuario registrado quiere publicar</button>

<!-- MODAL THAT WORKS -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="modalPublishWithAccount">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
        I'm the modal that works
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /MODAL THAT WORKS -->

<!-- MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg registration-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="solicitarArriendoWithAccountModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content registration-modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header registration-modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body modal-body-img registration-modal-body text-center col-lg-8 col-md-8 pb-5 pt-0 mx-auto">
        I'm the modal that doesn't work
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /MODAL THAT DOESN'T WORK -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Won't work on my code. Only the dark screen come up. All the other modals work (I have about 5).

Answer (score 0):

check number of div which are opened and number of div which are closed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).